# Show Related Products by Tag (Shopify)

Tags: shopify

I have a "Related Products" section on my Product page. Right now it shows products that a related by "collection". Is it possible to show related products that have the same Tag?

This is my **related-products.liquid** code.

Thanks.

```
{% assign number_of_products = 4 %}
{% assign number_of_products_to_fetch = number_of_products | plus: 1 %}

{% if collection == null or collection.handle == 'frontpage' or collection.handle == 'all' %}
  {% assign found_a_collection = false %}
  {% for c in product.collections %}
      {% if found_a_collection == false and c.handle != 'frontpage' and c.handle != 'all' and c.all_products_count > 1 %}
         {% assign found_a_collection = true %}
         {% assign collection = c %}
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if collection and collection.products_count > 1 %}
   <div class="related">
      <h1>You Might Also Like</h1>
      <div class="products clearfix">
         {% assign current_product = product %}
         {% assign current_product_found = false %}

         {% for product in collection.products limit: number_of_products_to_fetch %}
            {% if product.handle == current_product.handle %}
               {% assign current_product_found = true %}
            {% else %}
               {% unless current_product_found == false and forloop.last %}
                  <li>
                    <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="product__image" title="{{ product.title | escape }}">
                      <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '350x350' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
                    </a>
                  </li>
               {% endunless %}
            {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
       </div>
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are tagged products you want to display inside the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Let's change up your for loop that traverses the collection of items, and ignores items that are **not tagged.**

```
     {% for product in collection.products limit: number_of_products_to_fetch %}
        {% if product.handle == current_product.handle %}
           {% assign current_product_found = true %}
        {% else %}
           {% unless current_product_found == false and forloop.last %}
           {% if current_product_found.tags contains 'best-tag-ever' %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="product__image" title="{{ product.title | escape }}">
                  <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: '350x350' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
                </a>
              </li>
           {% endif %}
           {% endunless %}
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

Note! This will still only traverse through the collection that is provided. That means that the products that will show up need to be a) included in such collection, and b) be tagged with `'best-tag-ever'`. If you would like to show products from the entire store instead of said collection, you can swap out that collection for the `all` collection which has every product in your store.

Comment: I dont want to hard code the tag or collection, I just want shopify to show the related products to that specific product.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code for adding the related products using Tags -

```
{% assign number_of_related_products_to_show = 2 %} 
    {% assign current_product = product %} {% assign current_product_tags = product.tags %} 
    {% assign found_first_match = false %} {% assign found_second_match = false %} 
    {% assign first_related_product = true %} 
    {% paginate collections.all.products by 1000 %} 
    {% for product in collections.all.products %} 
    {% unless product.handle == current_product.handle %}
     {% for tag in product.tags %} 
    {% if current_product_tags contains tag %} 
    {% if found_first_match == false %} 
    {% assign found_first_match = true %} 
    {% assign first_match = tag %} 
    {% else %} 
    {% assign found_second_match = true %}
     {% assign second_match = tag %}
     {% endif %}
     {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
     {% if found_first_match == true %}
     {% if first_related_product == true %} 
    {% assign first_related_product = false %}
        Related products
        {% endif %}
     {% if product.tags contains first_match or product.tags contains second_match %} 
    {% include 'product-grid-item' with collection.handle %} 
    {% endif %} 
    {% endif %} 
    {% endunless %} 
    {% endfor %} 
    {% if first_related_product == false %}
        {% endif %}
     {% endpaginate %}
```